# Button in view doesn't work from view container

Tags: swift, uiview

I have a view container in my view controller, which is stretched to whole screen. User interaction enabled is on. When I open another view via this view container in this view controller, button is clickable but doesn't respond. What should I do to make it work?

ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var viewContainer: UIView!

var views: [UIView]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    views = [UIView]()
    views.append(LoginVC().view)
    views.append(RegisterVC().view)

    for v in views{
        viewContainer.addSubview(v)
    }

    viewContainer.bringSubview(toFront: views[1])
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func switchViewAction(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    print("clicked - segment")
    self.viewContainer.bringSubview(toFront: views[sender.selectedSegmentIndex])
}
```

[image: container view]

and this is the button in the another view

```
@IBAction func registerTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Clicked - register")
}
```

I used [Managing View Controllers](https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers/) tutorial to make it working.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @Khushbu added some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace the entire `ViewController`, not just the `View`.

```
@IBAction func switchViewAction(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    self.viewContainer.bringSubview(toFront: views[sender.selectedSegmentIndex])
}
```

Your current code is just replacing `LoginVC`'s **view** with `RegisterVC`'s **view**, instead of replacing `LoginVC` with `RegisterVC`. When you do that, you leave behind the `ViewController` in charge of actually responding to any interaction.

You'll have to rework your code to keep track of the ViewControllers instead of just their views. Then, instead of adding all of your views to `viewContainer` and moving them to the front when you need to change the current view, you should set the your child ViewController (the ViewController embedded in your container) to the ViewController you want to show (either `LoginVC` or `RegisterVC`).